# ASP.NET TextBox control is not wraping

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to wrap text in `asp:textbox` control. This is code of my textbox:

```
<asp:textbox
    runat="server"
    ReadOnly ="true"
    BackColor="Transparent"
    BorderStyle="None"
    TextMode="MultiLine"
    Wrap="true"
    style=" text-align: center;font-size: medium;" 
    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'>>
</asp:textbox>
```

And this is the effect:

[image]

I got horizontal scrollbar, and text is not wrapping. I want to achieve word wrapping without scrollbar (control should exceed its height).
I tried adding CSS wrapping tags, but effect is the same.

Comment: @SalahAkbari its working! Exactly what I wanted! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your CSS, then it works just fine:

```
style="white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"
```